# Renewing the facebook extended token before it expires

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am facing problems renewing the facebook extended token which is valid for 60 days, before it expires. 
I am following the steps mentioned on this page
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending

I called the endpoint https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=...&client_secret=...&redirect_uri= ... with curl_get_file_contents

and i got the "code"

Then as the next step i call the endpoint oauth/authorize?code=...&client_id=...&redirect_uri=... using curl_get_file_contents with the code i recieved in the previous step but dont get anything in return. What am i missing?

Facebook docs say "Once you've retrieved the code from Facebook's server you then need to ship it to the client via a secure channel. Once that's done, you need to make a request from the client to this endpoint:"

what do they mean by ship it to the client via a secure channel? And what do they mean by make a request from the client to this endpoint? any examples you can give me on how to call these urls using the php sdk.

Comment: You can not extend an already extended token – the whole point of deprecating offline access a while ago was that apps can not go on forever acting on a user’s behalf, but need user interaction at least every 60 days to get a new token. And the part from the docs that you are quoting has nothing to do with extending tokens, it just generally describes that it doesn’t matter how you get a token – you can use a token obtained server-side on the client and vice versa.

Comment: Is there a doc which refers to getting a new token with user interaction before the existing one expires?

Comment: That happens with the normal login flow.

Answer (score -1):

The token will automaticaly refresh his expire timestamp after an interaction between the user and your application.

Comment: Can you guide me to the doc which details on how to get the expire time of the access_token so i can find out for sure if the access_token expire timestamp has changed?

Comment: Is it so hard to look through the docs a little bit on your own? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug